# Ansible try to query an AWS TG using community-aws module to get TG status

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to query an AWS TG using the [community-aws module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/aws/elb_target_group_info_module.html) to get TG status,
I want to query a specific TG every few seconds until I see that the state of that TG is "healthy".

So far I have this task in ansible:

```
- name: Gather information about the target group attached to a particular LB
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.6
  register: target_health
  community.aws.elb_target_group_info:
    region: "{{AWS_REGION}}"
    target_group_arns: "{{TARGET_GROUP_ARN}}"
    collect_targets_health: yes
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

- debug: msg="return_target_health ={{target_health}}"

- name: iterate items
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.targets_health_description }}"
  with_items: "{{ target_health.target_groups }}"
```

The playbook output:

```
  TASK [service : debug] ****************************************************
  ok: [service.devbed-vpc.] => {
      "msg": "return_target_health ={'target_groups': [{'target_group_arn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:4795703XXXXX:targetgroup/Testbed-Vee-8124-TG/b8b282d82426331c', 'target_group_name': 'Testbed-Vee-8124-TG', 'protocol': 'HTTP', 'port': 8124, 'vpc_id': 'vpc-19333d7f', 'health_check_protocol': 'HTTP', 'health_check_port': '8124', 'health_check_enabled': True, 'health_check_interval_seconds': 10, 'health_check_timeout_seconds': 5, 'healthy_threshold_count': 5, 'unhealthy_threshold_count': 2, 'health_check_path': '/health', 'matcher': {'http_code': '200'}, 'load_balancer_arns': ['arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:4795703XXXXX:loadbalancer/app/Testbed-Vee-ALB/e2b8546cb7196017'], 'target_type': 'instance', 'protocol_version': 'HTTP1', 'stickiness_enabled': 'false', 'deregistration_delay_timeout_seconds': '300', 'stickiness_type': 'lb_cookie', 'stickiness_lb_cookie_duration_seconds': '86400', 'slow_start_duration_seconds': '0', 'load_balancing_algorithm_type': 'round_robin', 'tags': {'Env': 'Testbed'}, 'targets_health_description': [{'target': {'id': 'i-0b9b6e5a2775bXXXX', 'port': 8124}, 'health_check_port': '8124', 'target_health': {'state': 'healthy'}}, {'target': {'id': 'i-0feb307f8bdf6XXXX', 'port': 8124}, 'health_check_port': '8124', 'target_health': {'state': 'healthy'}}]}], 'failed': False, 'changed': False}"

  TASK [service : iterate items] ********************************************
  ok: [service.devbed-vpc.] => (item={'target_group_arn': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:4795703XXXXX:targetgroup/Testbed-Vee-8124-TG/b8b282d82426331c', 'target_group_name': 'Testbed-Vee-8124-TG', 'protocol': 'HTTP', 'port': 8124, 'vpc_id': 'vpc-19333d7f', 'health_check_protocol': 'HTTP', 'health_check_port': '8124', 'health_check_enabled': True, 'health_check_interval_seconds': 10, 'health_check_timeout_seconds': 5, 'healthy_threshold_count': 5, 'unhealthy_threshold_count': 2, 'health_check_path': '/health', 'matcher': {'http_code': '200'}, 'load_balancer_arns': ['arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:4795703XXXXX:loadbalancer/app/Testbed-Vee-ALB/e2b8546cb7196017'], 'target_type': 'instance', 'protocol_version': 'HTTP1', 'stickiness_enabled': 'false', 'deregistration_delay_timeout_seconds': '300', 'stickiness_type': 'lb_cookie', 'stickiness_lb_cookie_duration_seconds': '86400', 'slow_start_duration_seconds': '0', 'load_balancing_algorithm_type': 'round_robin', 'tags': {'Env': 'Testbed'}, 'targets_health_description': [{'target': {'id': 'i-0b9b6e5a2775bXXXX', 'port': 8124}, 'health_check_port': '8124', 'target_health': {'state': 'healthy'}}, {'target': {'id': 'i-0feb307f8bdf6XXXX', 'port': 8124}, 'health_check_port': '8124', 'target_health': {'state': 'healthy'}}]}) => {
      "msg": [
          {
              "health_check_port": "8124",
              "target": {
                  "id": "i-0b9b6e5a2775bXXXX",
                  "port": 8124
              },
              "target_health": {
                  "state": "UNhealthy"
              }
          },
          {
              "health_check_port": "8124",
              "target": {
                  "id": "i-0feb307f8bdf6XXXX",
                  "port": 8124
              },
              "target_health": {
                  "state": "healthy"
              }
          }
      ]
  }
```

I want to run this task until both **"target_health:states"** are healthy.
I wasn't able to do it, I was able to put the output to the file and then run a shell script that checks if the string "state": "healthy" is accruing more than once.

But then I realized the file is actually static and I write to it only once and only then I run the script in a loop which doesn't make any sense.

Is there a way for creating this query until I get the proper result I want without writing it to a file?

Answer (score 1):

The [`retries:`, `delay:`, and `until:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) keywords will interest you

```yaml
- name: Gather information about the target group attached to a particular LB
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3.6
  register: target_health
  community.aws.elb_target_group_info:
    region: "{{AWS_REGION}}"
    target_group_arns: "{{TARGET_GROUP_ARN}}"
    collect_targets_health: yes
  retries: 12
  delay: 5
  until: >-
    {{ (target_health.target_groups[0].targets_health_description|length) 
    ==  target_health.target_groups[0].targets_health_description
        | selectattr("target_health.state", "eq", "healthy") | list | length }}
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Alternatively, one could use [awscli's wait](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elbv2/wait/target-in-service.html), if you'd prefer to let awscli stall for you (it's not very ansible-y, but it makes for a ton less playbook log output as ansible retries)

```yaml
- command: >-
    aws --region {{ AWS_REGION }} elbv2 wait 
    target-in-service --target-group-arn {{ TARGET_GROUP_ARN | quote }}
```

Comment: I guess something in the parsing is wrong because I get:

fatal: [service.devbed-vpc.]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ (target_health.target_groups|length) !=  target_health.target_groups\n    | selectattr(\"target_health.state\", \"eq\", \"healthy\") | list | length }}' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ({{ (target_health.target_groups|length) !=  target_health.target_groups\n    | selectattr(\"target_health.state\", \"eq\", \"healthy\") | list | length }}): 'dict object' has no attribute 'target_health'"}

Comment: ah, sorry, I missed the `msg: {{ item.targets_health_description }}` part, so the `selectattr` was one level too low

Comment: First of all thanks a lot, just wanted to update you that I ended up using the awscli, and it's working perfectly.
regarding the more ansbley way, It still fails, looks like something in the comparing is no working, because it doesn't seem to verify my healthy TG.

  FAILED - RETRYING: Gather information about the target group attached to a particular LB(2) (2 retries left).
  FAILED - RETRYING: Gather information about the target group attached to a particular LB(2) (1 retries left).

Comment: Ah, I see: I invented the test since `until:` waits for true, but I had it written with `!=`; sorry, I don't have a TG to test the behavior so was coding in a textbox. But I'm glad the awscli method works for you. Please consider accepting the answer to let others know it solved your question